# Can quDit gates be non-unitary

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, unitarity

I have derived a quantum quDit gate that is implemented by photon Fock state inteference. It turns out to be non-unitary. I thought I must have made a mistake, so I have checked several times. I know a qubit gate must be unitary, but can a quDit gate be non-unitary?

Answer (score 2):

No, a qudit gate must also be unitary, just as all quantum gates. What can be done, however, is to *probabilistically* implement a non-unitary gate (in fact, *any* non-unitary operation).  If your gate is e.g. only implemented conditioned on the detection (or non-detection) of a photon, then this is possible.